# HTML Special Characters not rendered properly

Tags: html

I've setup VestaCP on a 2 identical Debian 7 Servers. Strangers on server one the special characters display properly out of the box, but on the Primary server, the special characters are not being rendered correctly, they give the black "?" instead. Both server's are exact same software and config. writes here..

I've tried setting

```
 /etc/apache2/conf.d/charset
    /home/admin/conf/web/apache2.conf
    /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

    in .htaccess
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AddCharset UTF-8 .html
```

but it doesn't resolve at all. Please help me.
Interestingly, the pages (quite and old site) use

in their header.

Please check page here : `http://168.235.66.20:8080/`

Answer (score 0):

The data is encoded using `Windows-1215` not `UTF-8`. You should convert it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You should change in your HTML :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

With :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```